# Auto-Detect Tab Width in Atom?

Tags: format, settings, atom-editor

I know I can specify the tab-width for *all* documents and I can have Atom auto-detect the usage of tab characters versus spaces but is there any way to *auto-detect* tab-*width*?

I am working with files that use both 2-space width and 4-space width. Combined with how Atom interacts with tabs (automatically prepending multiples of four when I make a new line and treating four contiguous spaces as a single character) this makes for a pretty frustrating experience.

Is there any simple way of having Atom switch between 4- and 2-width tabs automatically?

Comment: Have you considered using EditorConfig?

Comment: Awesome! I've installed that now... but it doesn't appear to solve the problem of a previously existent malformed file. It does say that there's a command for fixing them but it doesn't appear to be something I put in a terminal so I have no idea how to use it.

I might end up doing something like `cat file.py | sed 's/  /    /g' > file.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a script for converting files from one tab-width to another. (Assuming "tabs" are spaces.)

I think the first few lines describe its usage well enough but just in case; the first argument must specify the file's current tab-width. (You'll have to check this yourself.) The second argument specifies the desired tab-width. Third argument is the filename and the final argument is the destination for the modified file.

E.g. To change from 2-width to 4.
`chtabwidth 2 4 "./file.py" "./moddedFile.py"`

Note: Do *not* save the file to itself. It appends to the end of the file it is reading and will run forever. (This was the first thing I did and I made a 20MB file before I realized why it was hanging.) Actually, you know what, I'll add a condition to ensure it never happens. There, done.

```
#!/bin/bash

old_width="$1"
new_width="$2"
file="$3"
newfile="$4"

if [[ "$file" == "$newfile" ]]; then
  echo "Don't save to the same file!!"
  exit
fi

IFS=

while read -r p || [[ -n $p ]]; do
  indent_len=$(echo "$p" | egrep -o "^ *" | tr -d '\012\015' | wc -m)
  tab_num=$(( indent_len / old_width ))
  new_indent_len=$(( tab_num * new_width ))
  new_indent=$(printf '%*s' $new_indent_len '')
  revised=$(echo ${new_indent}$(echo "$p" | egrep -o "[^ ].*$"))
  echo "$revised" >> "$newfile"
done <"$file"
```

PS. I hate bash programming.

PPS. Zero warranty; don't blame me if random code you downloaded from the Internet sets your lunch on fire.